# Extract Multiple Sub-strings Between Brackets/Parentheses in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have various strings (formatted as text) that have a similar syntax in column F. Eg:

`1t ttn TEST FAILED (9-5 passOne, 21-7 & 877-12 passTwo)`

I want to extract the numbers within the brackets into separate cells. There may be anywhere between 1 and 5 different numbers.

The numbers will always contain a dash (-) somewhere in the middle and may have up to 3 digits either side of the dash.

Is this possible? I've been through previous questions and can't find anything that answers this.

Edit to show entered JvdV formula:

[image]

Comment: Would there ever by numbers containing a hyphen (-) outside the brackets? And yes it's possible, have you tried anything that gets you started? Sidenote, please include your version of Excel.

Comment: So result will contain this hyphen? From your sample data the result will be `9-5`, `21-7`, `877-12`?

Comment: Hi JvdV, it's unlikely but possible.

Comment: Hi Harun, yes with each of those appearing in a different cell. Eg D1 = 9-5 D2 = 21-7 D3 = 877-12

Comment: Another question; would the part that is inside brackets always at the end of the string?

Comment: Hi JvdV, yes, always.

Comment: And what about the Excel version?

Comment: Hi JvdV, its 2016.

Answer (score 3):

With Excel 2016:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>`"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE($A1,1,FIND("(",$A1),""),")",""),"&","&")," ","</s><s>`")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(., '-')][translate(., '`-','')*0=0]["&COLUMN(A1)&"]"),"`","")
```

Confirm through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Drag right, and down for all lines of data.

---

This assumed:

- Substring of interest (between paranthesis) is always at the end.
- Numbers with the hyphen as a delimiter may occur outside this substring and are not wanted in our results.

The trick here is to first sanitize the string and find the opening-paranthesis and remove everything prior to that using `REPLACE()`. Then, just `SUBSTITUTE()` the closing-paranthesis. The remainder can be split on spaces using `FILTERXML()`. To prevent errors and unwanted results I subsituted the ampersand and included accent graves to prevent Excel to recognize these substrings as dates. For more insight on the used xpath and the workings of `FILTERXML()` I'd like to refer you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837697/9758194).

Comment: Hi JvdV, thanks for this. Unfortunately, it gives me a #VALUE! error.

Comment: @robsmith, what is your exact input string? Also, are you a 100% sure you have entered this as array-formulae?

Comment: Hi, JvdV, I entered as an array and tested it on the example I put in the question.

Comment: @Robsmith, do you have a screenshot of your exact formula and the data? As you can see, it worked on my end just fine

Comment: Hi JvdV, it's strange. I've added a screenshot.

Comment: @Robsmith, I'm unfortunately unable to reproduce the error. It works fine on all versions of Excel (including 2016) that I have access to trying this.

Comment: Thanks for all your help

Comment: @Robsmith, any luck yet?